# Error reporting Freeform submission jumps to top of page despite auto form anchor

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I'm using Freeform 1.7.2 and since version 1.6.2 a form anchor is automatically added:

> Added form anchor to be automatically generated so inline error returns can focus down to form, if it's lower down on page.

Yet, the submission still jumps to the top of the page if there is an error. I asked a similar question before, but this was before the name anchor was added. Shouldn't this now work by itself?

Here's my super simple code:

```
{{ craft.freeform.form("formName", {
   instructionsBelowField: true,
   useRequiredAttribute: true,
}).render() }}
```

Comment: Unless you provide a little bit more information for us (what works, what does not work, how it is supposed to work eg via URL param or route param/Javascript or whatever, are there any console errors) it would be more useful to contact the creator of the plugin.

Comment: I know Robin, but this is the way Solspace advices me to ask for support. But I'll ask them directly and post the answer here then.

Comment: Just to clarify, we encourage the Craft Stack Exchange for how-to type questions. If you believe you are encountering a bug, you can of course use our Support Request ticket system. :)

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if this was a bug, but apparently it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've recently discovered that this feature is not always reliable unfortunately. However, we're working on addressing this and coming up with a better solution in the coming weeks. Sorry for any inconvenience.